# 1146 Table 'Accounting.users' doesn't exist Cake\Database\

Tags: cakephp, authentication, find

I'm working with cakephp3. I want to make login page. Name of table in Accounting database is 'users'.

This is my code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class UsersController extends AppController {

public function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request->data;
        $cnt = $data->Users->find()
                ->count();
        if ($cnt > 0) {
            $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->set('error', 'username or password is incorrct ');
        }
    }
}}
```

and this is Users.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class UsersTable extends Table {

}
```

after login in login page:

> Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

In your opinion, what is the problem.

Comment: Just look at the variable where you are referring to `Users`. I'd suggest to use an IDE with proper code inspection that would flag such mistakes. Also CakePHP ships with an authentication layer, you should use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

`$data` is not a Table object.

```
    $data = $this->request->data;
    $cnt = $data->Users->find()
```

This is pretty obvious.

I strongly recommend you to take some time and learn about debugging techniques and how to tackle this kind of problem and error messages. A developer should be able to resolve this kind of problem pretty quickly without external help. This is considered normal ever days work for a developer.

1) Read the whole error message 2) Search for it on Google and Stackoverflow, it is *very* unlikely nobody else ever got that message before. 3) Act according to whatever the cause of the error message is.

In the case of this error message debug what kind of object you're dealing with and figure out why it is not the object you expect it to be. Going trough the call stack helps. Use Xdebugs profiler for that, it's a great tool.

Also *don't* use variable names like `$cnt` I assume this is supposed to mean "account" which doesn't even fit into the context it is used. It's very bad named. Instead use proper variable names that are readable and fit into the context. It is a totally wrong assumption that keeping variable names short is any kind of time saver - it is clearly not. The next person working with this will need a dictionary or do a lot of guesswork on what these variables mean.

Comment: I copied this code from another project that was working properly.

Comment: I copied this code from another project that was working properly.              stack is  a place for any question. Anyway thanks for your advice.

Comment: Copy and paste fail I would say then. This *can't* work and it *doesn't* work. It is technically **impossible** that the request array somehow  magically turns into an UsersTable object...

Comment: @Digipng StackOverflow is _not_ the place for _any_ question. **http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic** | **http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  $cnt = $data->Users->find()->count(); use $cnt = $this->{$this->modelClass}->find('count');

Comment: 'count' for find('count') gives an error. I instead of this put find()->count(). but with this, users will be redirect to index with right or false passwords.